# React how re-mount component after route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i'm using react-redux in my project.

I have some component where i'm dispatch some action and get data from reducer into a component on **componentWillMount** method here is problem when i change to route componentWillMount method not firing my actions or anything else. for that i need to refresh page.

here is my **componentWillMount** Method:

```
 componentWillMount() {

        console.log("d")
        this
            .props
            .getChartData()
        data = this.props.chartData
    }
```

and here is my **main.js** where i import my components and assign routing.

```
import CompA from 'components/CompA'
import CompB from 'components/CompB'



const App = () => (
    <Container fluid>
        <div>
          <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/page-a" component={ComponentA} />
              <Route exact path="/page-b" component={ComponentB} />
            </Switch>
          </main>
        </div>
    </Container>      
)

export default App
```

where i mistake or what i need to do with it?

and its **index.js:**

```
const target = document.querySelector('#root')

console.log(store.getState())
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div className="row">
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use redux you should use mapStateToProps to change the state in your component

Comment: i already use it, here is another problem i think because my other components too behave like that when gi go to another route from menu eg: <Link  to="/component-a"></Link> component mount and get state once only i think my components are not rendering on every route change

Comment: How it @M_Badrah ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ConnectedRouter from the package react-router-redux, which is now deprecated.

For react-router 4, You need to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) react-router-dom to wrap the component before connecting it like this:
`withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent))`
You can get also get the match, location, history properties via props once the component is wrapped in withRouter.

For further information on withRouter, you can visit the following link:  https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom and i tried now withRouter make it in my component like that: withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentB)) but nothing changed

Comment: and yes i'm using connectedRouter

Comment: @user3348410 Can you check the browser console and see if you're getting any error messages ?

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` supplied to `ChartComponent`.

Comment: @user3348410 Can you remove Connected router and use import BrowserRouter instead and try again ?

Comment: @user3348410 You can import it from react-router-dom. `import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: I Tried and getting the extra error like : Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188884/discussion-between-samu-joseph-and-user3348410).